# CSS - text-overflow not working with percentage based div

Tags: html, css

In my div, it's defined the `width` in percentage based. But the `text-overflow` not working as i expect.

how to manage this?

```css
div {
    width:50% /* instead giving 500px works!*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `;` after your `width` property and hence your other property is ignored.. So even your `width` won't be applied nor `white-space` because the previous statement is not terminated with the `;`

```
div {
    width:50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h19a3fbr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is that your semicolon (;) is missing after the `width` property. Because of that it ignore first two properties. End semicolon is missing, both properties are recognize as one property.

```
div {
     width:50%; /* instead giving 500px works!*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only problem is semi-colon, ellipsis will work for percentage too.
Your code will be fine, once you add semi-colon